# Use of 'Cheers to that"

Tags: expressions

I have a doubt concerning the usage of the expression 'Cheers to that'.

I know it's usually used to celebrate a statement. But, I have sometimes heard it being used more as a reply to show agreement.

e.g.:

- I hope we both pass the test.

- Cheers to that!

Is this use correct?

Thank you

Comment: Who and where are people saying "Cheers to that"? It's not something I'd say but there are a lot of variations of English around the world.

Answer (score 2):

It's not so much 'is it correct?" as "do people use it in that sense?"

People say "Cheers!" when they are about to have a [usually alcoholic] drink together; more recently, it's sometimes used to mean "Thank you" or "Goodbye". We can also say "I'll drink to that" to mean that we very much agree with what someone has said, so it could be logical to use "Cheers" in the first sense.

Comment: People also say "Here's to ____" with the same meaning as "I'll drink to ____"; I wonder if there's some confusion there?

Comment: The meaning "Cheers" may have changed over time: my perception is that it used to be the host or person buying a round of drinks who would raise their own glass and say "Cheers" as in minor toast to indicate all could now drink.  Now it seems to be the recipient who says it, allowing the word to become a substitute for "thank you".  It may also have started to replace "Cheerio" meaning "goodbye".